# Time complexity of singly linked list in different situations

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, time-complexity, big-o

A singly linked list has n nodes and the address of i-th node is provided analyze the following situations.

1.Add a new node between (i-1)-th node and i-th node, assuming that the address of i-th node cannot be changed.

2. Repeat 1,but allow the address of i-th node change.

I think no matter whether it allow the address of i-th node change,the time complexity are both O(n),n depend to the number of linked list.

I don't know the influence on whether the address of i-th node change.

Comment: adding a single new node is O(1) surely?

Comment: @MitchWheat u don't have the address of the node before the position u want to add. It will cost O(n)

Answer (score 1):

You have a reference to i-th node and you can "change the address", then you can just insert a new node *after* the ith, and copy the content of ith node to a new one:

```
// `node` is a reference to the i-th node
// `value` is a value for a new inserted node
struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
new_node->next = node->next;
new_node->value = node->value; // copy the content
node->next = new_node;
node->value = value;
```

And this is an O(1) operation.